# SageMaker endpoint AWS Lambda inference Issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, aws-lambda, postman, amazon-sagemaker

I've deployed a category trained model and hosted the endpoint.. and trying to inference this, but have a issue.. basically we take a short description i.e "laptop screen" this should return a category i.e "Hardware" the problem i'm facing is that i just seem to get this error when inferencing this via postman.

i.e if i send this  `{"data":"laptop screen"}`

i get this error in the body

```json
{
    "errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)",
    "errorType": "JSONDecodeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        [
            "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
            21,
            "lambda_handler",
            "result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())"
        ],
        [
            "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
            354,
            "loads",
            "return _default_decoder.decode(s)"
        ],
        [
            "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
            339,
            "decode",
            "obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())"
        ],
        [
            "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py",
            357,
            "raw_decode",
            "raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None"
        ]
    ]
}
```

this is my lambda function:

```py
import os
import io
import boto3
import json
import csv

ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = data['data']
    print(payload)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                        ContentType='text/csv',
                                        Body=payload)
    print(response)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
    
    return result
```

Ive added this to admin IAM role too

```json
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint",
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

Any assistance would be ace, i feel im pretty close it works fine when it comes to predicting priority, but need help when predicting category string.

Comment: For the future, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code snippets (done it for you this time).

Comment: ace cheers bud appreciate it.

Comment: In postman, did you try sending `{"data":"laptop screen", "content-type": "text/csv"}` ?

Comment: Hi Bud, cheers for the response, yep i tried this and still throwing the same error? :/

Comment: can you post the lambda cloudwatch entries? Is there any chance `response` is empty?

Comment: oh and nope its not empty, let me know if you want me to make the logs more clear, its strange all i want to do is return the correct category labels and succeeds with the request but still throws the same error

Comment: when i invoke {"data":"laptop screen"} on a different endpoint with a model to predict a number based on urgency i.e '1-7' this is correct, but when i invoke the same data on an endpoint based on a category label i.e 'Hardware' i get this error thrown? :/

Comment: cloudwatch: {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '26ce19c8-38e7-4c7d-9010-a69fda9922fc', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '26ce19c8-38e7-4c7d-9010-a69fda9922fc', 'x-amzn-invoked-production-variant': 'default-variant-name', 'date': , 'content-type': 'text/csv; charset=utf-8', 'content-length': '9'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'ContentType': 'text/csv; charset=utf-8', 'InvokedProductionVariant': 'default-variant-name', 'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f187f618940>}
then proceeds with Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0): as shown

Answer (score 1):

For your lambda function, I think the error might be with the way you're passing your payload in, take the following code snippet.

```
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                       ContentType='application/json',
                                       Body=payload)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
```

Adjust the payload that you are passing in to use json.dumps() to encode your data properly for the endpoint.

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own

Comment: Hi Bud, thanks for the heads up.. I tried this when submitting  {"data":"laptop screen"}

Comment: data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                       ContentType='text/csv',
                                       Body=payload)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())

Comment: and got this error {"errorMessage": "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)", "errorType": "JSONDecodeError", "stackTrace": [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 22, "lambda_handler", "result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())"], ["/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", 354, "loads", "return _default_decoder.decode(s)"], ["/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", 339, "decode", "obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())"], ["/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", 357, "raw_decode", "raise JSONDecodeError(\"Expecting value\", s, err.value) from None"]]}

Comment: interesting, when i invoke {"data":"laptop screen"} json.dumps(data) does work on a different endpoint with a model to predict a number based on urgency i.e '1-7' this is correct, but when i invoke the same data on an endpoint based on a category label i.e should be returning response as 'Hardware' i get this same error thrown? even after adjusting the payload to use json.dumps()? could it be because i'm trying to predict a label and not a integer?

Comment: I think that might be an issue with your inference code then in the script you're providing or container you're bringing.

Comment: Hi Ram, would you suggest i rebuild the model and make sure the data is set correctly? im a bit confused by what you mean by container you're bringing?

Comment: The output of your model/response is what you need to configure within your model code itself based off of what you are trying to predict

Comment: Hi Ram, yes i have confirmed this in the model code so expect the response to be a label category i.e 'network', 'hardware', 'software' etc, when i send a short description i.e 'laptop screen' i should get this response as a category? many thanks

Comment: hi Ram, just a update i i send this request {"data":"checkpoint wrong username password users", "content-type": "text/csv"}

Comment: i get this response now, An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from container-2 with message "Unable to evaluate payload provided: Feature size of recordio-protobuf inference data 59 is not consistent with feature size of trained model 58.".